# Can I make an alias for a bitmap drawable in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have defined a bitmap in `/drawable/app_background_raw` as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/actual_png_file"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Now I want two copies of this defined - one as it is unchanged, and one rotated 90 degerees so that I can use it in portrait mode. I can create the rotated one as such:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:drawable="@drawable/app_background_raw">
</rotate>
```

..but how do I, with least overhead, create an unchanged copy of app_background_raw? I can obviously create another `RotationDrawable` rotated 0 degrees, but that feels a bit silly. Suggestions?

**Update**

This was a bad idea for this scenario, as Android seems to scale the bitmap for portait mode before I can rotate, but in any case I'm interested in knowing what the simplest way of creating an alias for a drawable is.